# KDE plasma 5 application menu is not working on multi screen

Tags: kde5, panel

I have a fresh installation of Arch Linux with KDE plasma.

```
KDE version: 5.23.2  
Kernel: 5.10.76-1-lts
Graphics server: X11
Graphics driver: nvidia
```

I have 1 external monitor connected to my laptop.
I created a standard panel on both screens and set the external monitor to my primary. When pressing the `super` key the application menu opens on the external monitor. The search box is not automatically focused, so clicking into it and typing anything into the search box does not show any results

[image]

When now clicking on the application menu button on the laptop screen and searching there everything works fine and the search results appear as expected

Now something else that is strange, when I press the `super` key and the application menu opens on the external monitor, the search is not automatically focused. Regardless, if I now start typing (nothing actually appears in the search box) and open the application menu on the laptop the entered text appears there.

Things I've tried:

- Switch primary screen from external to laptop; result was the opposite as described above, `super` would open the application menu on the laptop and searching didn't work there but only on the external monitor after opening the application menu by clicking on it
- Removing one of the panels completely; the application menu in the remaining panel still didn't work properly
- Installed nvidia-lts driver but no change

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a Nvidia or KDE issue, as I am having the same issue on a multi-monitor gentoo configuration.

Though I am unsure of what causes it, I have noticed that at least on my machine, it can be resolved if you use the broken search panel first upon boot.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Perhaps you could expand a little on your proposed solution: What do you mean by _"use"_ the search panel (i.e. what needs to be entered/clicked/...)?

Answer (score 0):

**Upstream KDE Bug:** https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=443131

This issue is not NVIDIA related, as also people with AMD GPUs are reporting this issue.

The workaround is to downgrade the kickoff applet, until the bug is fixed upstream or to only have one kickoff applet.

**I have written a guide to downgrade the kickoff applet on the [Manjaro Forum](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/no-search-results-in-application-launcher/91500/6)**

Basically you have to download the old kickoff applet and place it under `~/.local/share/plasma/plasmoids/`.

Many Greetings

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? I've spent more than a day trying to get the app menu working, to no avail so far. What is a "kickoff applet"? How would I get it to work in the cited directory? I honestly just want to use my computer and really, really don't want to learn all the internals of KDE mechanics. :(